# Is it possible to give some users access to just User Generated Content?

Tags: configuration, ugc

I need to give certain users access to just the User Generated Content.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so how I can achieve that please?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? By UGC you mean the Control Room, the UGC branch of the publication tree?

Answer (score 1):

I just gave this a quick try. 
Apparently if you create a new Group of users and give this group the UGC management right from the Publication security tab, it is not enough for your users to be able to access the Publication node, hence no way to see Comments or Ratings, neither from the UGC node nor from the control room.

I was able to enable UGC by also adding the Category management right to my Group, and not give any permissions on categories to that Group, therefore the users can see the Categories, but not the keywords in them, nor can they modify the categories.
There may be other work arounds possible by adding other management rights with minimal impact to your Group.

Comment: This does not work for me. I've yet to find the correct right/permission to enable the UGC shortcut under a publication short of Sys Admin!!

Comment: Strangely I see a ugc:PublicationRights entry in the Application Data tab which corresponds to my group??

Comment: I did my tests on Tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own investigations in 2011 SP1 HR1:

- The User Generated Content right only works on a User, not a Group (amazingly enough).
- A single user cant just have the User Generated Content right on its own - when I tried this my user saw no Publications at all. To get around this I gave the Virtual Folder Management right as well (which is just for Search Folders, so no editing capability on actual content).You could use a Group to manage this and add your User to the Group.
- Even with no rights at all the Control Room/Community option is still available to your user, but without any rights on a publication they cant see anything anyway. Having User Generated Content rights on my user alone didn't help here either, I had to have another right such as Virtual Folder Management.

So I ended up with:

1. A new user - **User A**.
2. A new Group - **Group A**, of which User A is a member - membership scope All.
3. In Security tab of my Publication I added **User A** with only *User Generated Content* right and **Group A** with only *Virtual Folder Management* right.

This allowed the User Generated Content node to appear under the Publication and the Control Room/Community to have a publication in its filter.